# Why there's a mem leak and how to fix it?

Tags: delphi, pointers, memory-leaks

```
unit Unit7;

interface

uses Classes;

type
  TListener = class(TThread)
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

  TMyClass = class
    o1,o2: Tobject;
    procedure FreeMyObject(var obj: TObject);
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

uses Windows, SysUtils;

var l: TListener;
    my: TMyClass;

procedure TListener.Execute;
var msg:TMsg;
begin
  while(GetMessage(msg, Cardinal(-1), 0, 0)) do
    if(msg.message=6) then begin
      TMyClass(msg.wParam).FreeMyObject(TObject(msg.lParam));
      Exit;
    end;
end;

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  o1:=TObject.Create;
  o2:=Tobject.Create; // Invalid pointer operation => mem leak
end;

destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
  if(Assigned(o1)) then o1.Free;
  if(Assigned(o2)) then o2.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyClass.FreeMyObject(var obj: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(obj);
end;

initialization
  l:= TListener.Create();
  my:=TMyClass.Create;

  sleep(1000); //make sure the message loop is set
  PostThreadMessage(l.ThreadID, 6, Integer(my), Integer(my.o2));
finalization
  l.Free;
  my.Free;
end.
```

I used the message handler to illustrate my problem as is so you understand it. The real design is a lot more complicated. The function 'FreeMyObject' actually Frees AND creates an instance using polymorphism paradigm, but this here is not needed. I only want to point out that the design should stay the same.

Now the question and problem - why it happens AND how to fix it? It seems 'if Assigned(o2)' doesn't fit it.

What I think of: Sending a pointer to my.o2 would free and nil o2 and I tries to do so, but I couldn't convert from pointer to object in the message handler, got no idea why.

Could anybody give a hand? Thanks

Comment: Does `Invalid pointer operation => mem leak` really belong in the line `o2:=Tobject.Create;`

Comment: @mjn. It probably belongs to the corresponding line in the destructor. :)

Comment: You'd better use values higher than WM_APP for message numbers. 6 is WM_ACTIVATE, and might cause trouble.

Comment: @netboy - if you still just want to [destroy the thread from another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897263/how-to-destroy-a-thread-from-the-main-thread) I would use the well known `while not Terminated do Something;` loop and terminate it by calling [Terminate](http://tinyurl.com/TThread-Terminate) or maybe I would try to consider using [event objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). They are IMHO better than message loop for your purpose. But it's just my opinion.

Comment: @daemon_x I'm fairly sure that the real code is quite different. I don't think there's much to be gained by critiquing this code since it has clearly been hacked out of a real program for the purpose of posting here.

Comment: @David - surely is, but almost every OP's question tends to the message loop, what I would avoid to use in thread concept. But it's just my opinion, no one can say it won't work, it's also the way for thread intercommunication.

Comment: FWIW, `if Assigned(x) then x.Free;` is an unnecessary pattern. Free already checks if x is assigned, so simply do `x.Free;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You free `o2` twice. Once as a result of the message and once from the destructor.

You think you are setting `o2` to `nil` when you call `FreeMyObject` but you are not. You are in fact setting `msg.lParam` to 0.

`o2` is a variable holding a reference to an object. You are passing the value of `o2` and when you pass by value you cannot modify the variable whose value you passed. So you need to pass a reference to `o2`. To do so you need to add an extra level of redirection and pass a pointer to `o2`, like so:

```
if(msg.message=6) then begin
  FreeAndNil(PObject(msg.lParam)^);
  Exit;
end;

...

PostThreadMessage(l.ThreadID, 6, 0, LPARAM(@my.o2));
```

You don't need `FreeMyObject`, you can just call `FreeAndNil` directly. And you don't need to pass an instance in the message.

I hope your real code isn't quite as weird as this!  ;-)

Comment: The recommended cast in PostThreadMessage that is backwards and future proof(64 bit) is PostThreadMessage(l.ThreadID,6,0,LParam(@my.o2));

Comment: @LU RD Thanks, you are quite right, I'll update that, I should know that since my own code says just that as of a couple of months ago!!

Comment: Yep, already tried this and failed. The problem is much elsewhere. Let B = class(A). In A this msg is sent where lparam=@Self - it should work. But won't. @Self will not point to the address where the reference to A is placed. Sadly, I lost 2 days till I found it. Thanks for the effort tho', accepted!

Comment: @netboy Yes, `@Self` is quite different from what you asked about. The basic idea is the same though. You need to pass a reference to the variable, not its value. `Self` is not what you should be passing, but presumably some field of an object.

Comment: But this message is sent from o2(it's a class, not just TOBject). No way to get its address unless Self is used. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @netboy I'm getting a little confused by these comments. However, if you need to call `FreeAndNil()` on a variable (local variable, field of instance etc.), then you just need to pass the address of that variable. That's all that's needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to `FreeAndNil` an object sending just object reference `Integer(my.o2)` is not enough - you need `Integer(@my.o2)`. You should also make corresponding changes in your code.

Since your code is difficult to debug I have written a simple demo to give an idea of necessary code changes:

```
type
  PObject = ^TObject;

procedure FreeObj(PObj: PObject);
var
  Temp: TObject;

begin
  Temp:= PObj^;
  PObj^:= nil;
  Temp.Free;
end;

procedure TForm17.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Obj: TList;
  PObj: PObject;

begin
  Obj:= TList.Create;
  PObj:= @Obj;
  Assert(Obj <> nil);
  FreeObj(PObj);
  Assert(Obj = nil);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's going on:

Program starts.  Initialization runs and sends a message to the thread, which calls `FreeAndNil` on the reference that gets passed in.  This sets the reference that gets passed in to **nil**, but it does not set the object field holding `o2` to **nil**.  That's a different reference.

Then in the destructor, since the field isn't **nil**, it tries to free it again and you get a double-free error (invalid pointer operation exception).  Since you raised an exception in the destructor, the TMyClass never gets destroyed and you get a memory leak from it.

If you want to do this right, pass an identifier of some type to `FreeMyObject` instead of a reference.  Like an integer `2`, or a string `o2`.  Then have `FreeMyObject` use this value to look up what it should be calling `FreeAndNil` on.  (If you have Delphi 2010 or later, that's pretty easy to do with RTTI.)  It's a little more work, but it will fix the errors you're seeing.

Comment: @David: The potential for encapsulation violation in your answer scares me... :P

Comment: it's not real code is it? How does passing a string, which doesn't work anyway since it doesn't get marshalled, and using rtti class as great encapsulation?!

Comment: your comment about the message loop is clearly off base. The message loop in this code runs in a thread and so does start while initializations are running.

Comment: @David, Oh, I see. It's talking about the other thread's messaging.  Nevermind, then. Editing that out...